# I need to change my digital fingerprints so it would like an ordinary computer from USA

Tags: firefox, browser, privacy, tor, google-cloud-platform

I know that Tor can do that, but as I understood, it changes your data every time. But I need constant data, so web site that I use would recognize me without any suspicion. Is there any way to do that? Can VM on Google Cloud Consol be enough for that particular reason?

Comment: What do you mean by *data* when you saye "it changes your data"? IP-Address? Cookies? What exactly?

Comment: Tor mainly changes IP address regularly. Otherwise, it looks like any other Tor install (unless you do something to make it look unique). Tor is detectable, even if you could force it to always exit from the USA. Most commercial VPNs are detectable, as are server farms where you might run your own VPN. How sophisticated the destination site is at detecting these situations is an open question. Can you do any probing with a fake account to test it?

Answer (score 2):

The terms *digital fingerprint* and *ordinary computer* are rather vague descriptions. It depends what you want to reach. Communication over the Internet is [IP-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol), so a server can at least see the IP address of a client trying to communicate with it (you!). If you are communicating with a web-server over the [HTTP-protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), i.e. browsing, more information might be revealed to the server, e.g. [cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie).

If you want to bypass [geo-blocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo-blocking), you have to first find out how the target blocks *foreign* clients. Usually it boils down to IP Blocking: used by services such as [BBC iPlayer](https://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer), this method compares your IP address with a list of known addresses (associated with a country) and decides whether to block or not.

To circumvent IP-Blocking you could use a VPN service. But beware that services also stay up-to-date and might block known VPN-addresses. Choose a VPN-Provider which regularly updates/changes its addresses.